# Unity mobile phones SSL connection error

Tags: c#, ssl, unity-game-engine, tcpclient, cryptographicexception

I'm struggling with an error when connecting to SSL server. I still get some cryptographic error when I do something like this:

```
_client = new TcpClient();

_sslStream = new SslStream(_client.GetStream(), false, (x, y, z, v) => true, null);
```

It always gives me CryptographicException: **Unsupported hash algorithm: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11**

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This issue does not occur in Unity 4.5.3f3 + try to connect to server like this:

```
_client.Connect (IPAddress.Parse("IP ADDRESS"), PORT);
```

because it crashes on mobile phones with some exception if domain name is used instead of ip address.